# Выровнять 2 кнопки влево и вправо в Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap4

Подскажите пожалуйста начинающему как сделать 2 кнопки чтобы выровнялись влево и вправо в одном ряду, а то у меня получается с переносом.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container pt-5">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="text-danger">Клиент с номером не найден. Давайте попробуем поискать по ФИО!</div>
        <input type="text" name="inputFIO" id="inputFIO" class="form-control" aria-describedby="FIOHelpBlock">
        <p id="FIOHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
          Введите фамилию и инициалы с которыми вы регистрировались в базе
        </p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Поиск</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="history.back();" class="btn btn-primary">Назад</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Уже нагуглил все что только мог, не могу понять как сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Например вот так.

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-5">
<form method="post">
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-5 mx-auto">
                <div class="text-danger">Клиент с номером не найден. Давайте попробуем поискать по ФИО!</div>
                <input type="text" name="inputFIO" id="inputFIO" class="form-control" aria-describedby="FIOHelpBlock" >
                <p id="FIOHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
                Введите фамилию и инициалы с которыми вы регистрировались в базе
                </p>
                <div class="flex-box">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Поиск</button>
                  <button type="button" onclick="history.back();" class="btn btn-primary">Назад</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: рад что помогло!!)))))))